# Core Data crash while fetching data from NSSet in one to many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am a newbie to core data relationship and now am facing a crash in my one to many relationship code. The code snippet is below

```
    -(void)fetchData{
   NSArray *tempArray = [[CLCoreDataAdditions sharedInstance]  getAllDocuments:@"MainCategory"];
    for (int i =0; i<tempArray.count; i++) {
        MainCategory *mainCategory = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",mainCategory.categoryId);
    }
    

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.categoryId == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
    NSArray *tempArray1 = [[CLCoreDataAdditions sharedInstance] getAllDocumentsFor:@"MainCategory" withPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"Temp %@",tempArray1);
    for (int i =0; i<tempArray1.count; i++) {
        MainCategory *mainCategory = [tempArray1 objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",mainCategory.categoryId);
        //NSLog(@"%@",mainCategory.subCategoryforMain);
        if(mainCategory.subCategoryforMain.count != 0) {
            NSArray *array = [mainCategory.subCategoryforMain allObjects];
            for (int j=0; j<array.count; j++) {
                SubCategory *subCategory = [array objectAtIndex:j];
                NSLog(@"%@",subCategory.categoryName);
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Crash Image is as follows:

[image]

Here is the interface declaration

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * categoryId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *subCategoryforMain;
@end

@interface MainCategory (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addSubCategoryforMainObject:(SubCategory *)value;
- (void)removeSubCategoryforMainObject:(SubCategory *)value;
- (void)addSubCategoryforMain:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeSubCategoryforMain:(NSSet *)values;
```

Comment: Could you add the MainCategory interface declaration?

Comment: I think MainCategory interface don't have the subCategoryforMain variable

Comment: @DanielAlbertini Please see the interface declaration in the edited post

Comment: And you have also declared your variable in your xcdatamodel?

Comment: Does the app work with **any** of `MainCategory`'s properties? What happens if you try to get or set the name?

Comment: Who knows what your CLCoreDataAdditions is doing... Could be delivering any kind of array that simply does not point to the correct object class.